# windows-equivalent of mac's "insert pattern" functionality for {find,search}ing/replacing text

Tags: regex, search, find, text-editors, replacement

surprised no one has asked this question yet.

is there any way to get the "insert pattern" functionality that is available on pretty much all mac apps with search and replace (except, ironically enough, in office)?

it seems this nifty feature is built into the operating system, and used by apps as a default if they do not have their own.

this is the only feature that i will miss when i move back to windows, and i'm hoping there is some way to add it in.

Comment: No, there's not. I doubt it's that widely available in Mac either. You'd definitely be much more likely to include any positive and more detailed answers if you provided a list of Windows apps for which you'd like such a functionality. And which Windows version is this about?